# How to represent different types of documents in a logical order

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, icomparer

I need to represent different types of documents in a logical order.
So I have a list of objects with IDs. I need to make a comparer which orders these objects by a "manual" rule. Order by id must be 2,32,5,12,8,43... and so on.

I use LINQ

```
documents.OrderBy(doc=> doc.Id, new DocumentsComparer<int>());

public class DocumentsComparer<T> : IComparer<int>
{
    ...???...
}
```

How to make such comparer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class DocumentsComparer<T> : IComparer<int>
{
    private List<int> order = new List<int>{2, 32, 5, 12, 8, 43};
    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        return order.IndexOf(x).CompareTo(order.IndexOf(y));
    }
}
```

if x and y can be outside of your known list, you'll have to add checks for that and handle those cases however.

Comment: If the 'order' list is big, I suggest using a Dictionary mapping instead.

Comment: It looks nice. But I can not run this comparer. It is not being called by linq query? I do not understand why. I edited my post.

Comment: @podeig It will not get called immediately after your use `orderby()`. That's something to do with the way `IEnumerable` works(lazy loading). To test it, you can try `documents.OrderBy(doc=> doc.Id, new DocumentsComparer<int>()).ToList()`;

Comment: I guess you can drop the Generic parameter `<T>` since it's not being used.